# Passing methods from secondary GUI to main GUI in python

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, pyqt5

So I have 2 GUIs. One is the main gui which has one push button to activate the second gui. The second gui is a simple calculator which sums two numbers when I push the button with external function.The second gui (the calculator) runs fine standalone However when I try to activate the second gui from the main one the program crashes so I probably doing something wrong.

Also if I change the code in main to this:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.SumCalcBtn.clicked.connect(self.OpenSecondWindow)

    def OpenSecondWindow(self):
        self.ex = SumCalculator(self)
        self.ex.show()
```

It runs but doesn't  do anything in second gui when I push the button to sum the numbers.(it seems the methods didn't pass to the instance)

I attach the code for better understanding:

Main.py

```
import sys
from calculators import summary
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from SummaryUI import Ui_SummaryUI
from SummaryMain import SumCalc
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow


class SumCalculator(SumCalc):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.SumCalcBtn.clicked.connect(self.OpenSecondWindow)

    def OpenSecondWindow(self):
        self.ex = SumCalc(self)
        self.ex.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

SummaryMain.py

```
import sys
from calculators import summary
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from SummaryUI import Ui_SummaryUI


class SumCalc(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SummaryUI):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_SummaryUI.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.CalculateSumBtn.clicked.connect(self.sum_function)

    def sum_function(self):
        number_a = int(self.FirstNumberInput.text())
        number_b = int(self.SecondNumberInput.text())
        sum = summary(number_a, number_b)
        self.SumResultsValue.setText(str(sum))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SumCalc()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `self.ex = SumCalc(self)` with `self.ex = SumCalc()` because the constructor(`__init__`) function of SumCalc does not take any argument (`def __init__(self)`)
or juts add parameter parent to SumCalc's constructor so it becomes `def __init__(self, parent=none)`